# How can I have a content type in Strapi that contains all items from another content type?

Tags: strapi

Is there a way to to have a content type for example 'Plans' and another content type named 'Dishes' and have any 'Plan' contain all dishes automatically?

The way it is setup now is like so:

[image]

That way you can select on each Dish to include all Plans. But the way it should be is to have all dishes in relation with any plan automatically so that there's no need to exclude/include a plan for each dish.

Comment: I think your relation should be `Plan has many Dishes`. That way a `Plan` entry can be linked to multiple `Dishes`, although that linking part will always be a manual process after you create a few entries in both the collections.

Comment: Yeah you're right and I have tried that. The downside is, indeed, the fact you have to manually add them.